# Can I get Minecraft Java AFTER buying Windows 10?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I bought Minecraft for Windows 10, and I also want Java so I can play with mods, but the Minecraft launcher doesn't say that I already have Minecraft, which I do. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Not a dupe. The other question asks if the Windows 10 version gives you the Java version for free; this one makes no such request.

Answer (score 0):

No, they are separate games, you have to pay for both.
[You can buy the Java edition here](https://minecraft.net/en-us/).